# Json Object Parse (prob a quick one)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Ok, so I stopped coding for a while and now im trying to get back into the flow of things as I've forgotten again.

Json code:

`"{\"Statistics\":{\"76561198047386802\":{\"LastUpdate\":1557255652}}}"`

jscode:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonData)
  const object = obj.Statistics.76561198047386802;
  console.log(object.LastUpdate);
```

I am trying to pass this code through to get the lastupdate value. I keep trying to use the numbers above but getting errors on the output. Can you please show me my idiotic mistake lol.

Comment: You can't use a number as a property name.

Comment: do you call jsonData by ajax or something like that?

Comment: More correctly: you can’t use a number with dot notation. The property name itself is fine. `obj.Statistics['76561198047386802']`

Comment: Thanks Ry Just was needing the proper format i suppose :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
...
const object = obj.Statistics['76561198047386802'];
...
```

Comment: This won’t work as a number, because `76561198047386802 === 76561198047386800`. It needs quotes.

Comment: ok. I edited my post